# mapStateToProps for React component that strictly depends on state shape AFTER fetching

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and Redux so pardon me if this is a trivial question.
I'm trying to build an app that simulates a building-room relationship. There is a one-to-many relationship between buildings and rooms, i.e each building can have many rooms. I'm following the recommendations [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape/) and use a normalized state shape like so

```js
{
    buildings: {
        1: {
            name: "A",
            rooms: [1, 2, 3]
        },
        2: {
            name: "B",
            rooms: [4, 5, 6]
        },
        // etc.
    },
    rooms: {
        1: {
            name: "405"
        },
        2: {
            name: "kitchen"
        },
        // etc.
    }
}
```

This is my initial state:

```
{
    buildings: {},
    rooms: {}
}
```

As for my react app, I have a `Building` and a `Room` component. The `Building` component renders all the `Rooms` it has. Each `Room` gets its id from its props passed in by the `Building`. The `Building` component also fetches data from the server.

```
class Building extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        fetchData() // fetching data using thunk and populate Redux state
    }

    render() {
        return {this.props.buildings[0].map(roomId => <Room key={roomId} />)}
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    buildings: state.buildings
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Building)
```

And here's how I set up the `Room` component:

```
class Room extends Component {
    render() {
        return {this.props.name}
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    name: state.rooms[ownProps.key].name
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Room)
```

The problem is while fetching the data, the initial state is empty and `mapStateToProps` of `Room` components fails because the state is not yet populated, thus `state.rooms[ownProps.key]` returns `undefined` and I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]
```

What would be the best practice to solve this problem? How do I (and should I) render a component whose state depends strictly on a Redux state that only becomes available after fetching?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is to write your rendering logic more defensively.  If you're fetching data on mount, then most likely `this.props.buildings` will either be undefined or empty on first render.  Your code should check for that case, and either return `null` during that first render, or have fallback values like an empty array.

See the post [Watch Out for Undefined State](https://daveceddia.com/watch-out-for-undefined-state/) for further thoughts on the topic.